# Remove relationship between two objects

Tags: parent, groups

I have an dae file which I import into blender version 2.76. There is one pool cue stick in this file.  There seems to be a relationship(shown by relationship line)between cue stick and another point which is at 0,0,0 as shown in the image below. I want to remove the relationship between this cue stick and I want that the tip of the cue stick be at 0,0,0 point.

Please let me know how to remove relationship between cue stick  with a point which is at 0,0,0

[image: Cue stick blender screenshot]

Comment: press Alt + P , and select "clear parent" :)

Comment: I tried Alt + P and selected clear parent but I can still see the relationship line

Comment: You should select the child object - in the screenshot it seems you selected the parent object instead, which is in fact the parent itself.

Comment: I selected the child objects with Shift+ G and then I pressed Alt + P.. Now instead of one object with parts of a cue 26 small objects( which are part of the cue stick are showing). How to join these 26 small cue objects. Is there a way by which without clearing the parent I can make the whole object point to 0,0,0

Comment: You could join the objects by pressing ctrl + J while having them selected, and then align the object the way you want it, yes :)

Comment: Hi MaVCArt. Job done. Thanks for your help

Comment: My please, glad I could help

Comment: For all clearity: use ALT+P in the 3D view, not the hierarchy view

Answer (score 3):

Click the object, then press `Alt + P`. This opens the `Clear Parent` menu.

Select `Clear and Keep Transformation`.

If this does not work for you, you may have selected the parent instead of the child.